# The Thévenin equivalent has an equivalent I–V characteristic only from the point of view of the load

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, short-circuit

I am reading about Thévenin's theorem on the [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem).

As you can see from the *Practical limitations* section, there is a one shortcoming that I don't understand.

> The Thévenin equivalent has an equivalent I–V characteristic only from
>   the point of view of the load.

Could anyone explain it more?

Answer (score 2):

Thevenin equivalent circuit is a way to represent a whole and relatively complex circuit into a simplest circuit diagram which give you same voltage between the nodes,that you use as reference to calculate the thevenin circuit. So you can see , it only fulfil one condition, it will give you same voltage at the nodes which you would get from main circuit and so current through the nodes will depend on the load you put between those two node.

You can not get any data about what would happen inside the main circuit and it's internal nodes.

So you can easily understand that  physically only nodes across the load is only two node which actually exist in the main circuit also. So if you wanna get I-V characteristics from thevenin circuit, you have no other choice but to use nodes across the load to collect data which represent data of main circuit.

FYI: I write this as far as I understand but It may be wrong.anyone is welcome to find my mistake.

Comment: I don't get why this answer is there, it is the exact same answer as I answer 2 hours before you...

Comment: I thought your answer is too short for anhnha and need I little bit more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It means that only from the load you have a I-V curve with a slope of R. If you want to know a specify voltage IN the thevenin's equivalent, you need to pass by more a classical analysis or make an other thevenin's equivalent from the POV of the component. Thevenin give you a bulk idea of how the load will react with a given source, but it lack details about the behaviour of the components in the source itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I think I've got it now.